# New files with pre-defined user template in text editors like VS Code

Tags: templates, visual-studio-code, text-editor

I have a template for .java files which I want every newly created .java file to have. Is there a feature in VS Code or any other text editors for this?

Comment: Look at the extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gruntfuggly.auto-snippet for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in [CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/cudatext/) editor. To use your java template, copy it to the subfolder in editor folder:

[cudatext]/data/newdoc

File must have .java extension.
When you call "File / New from template", editor suggests all templates.

Comment: Can I use it for competitive programming?

Comment: @AyushSingh It doesn't support it.